# SVN-Domino Designer integration

Tags: svn, subversive, svnkit, domino-designer-eclipse

I am trying the documented steps by Niklas Heidloff ([openntf](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/69BA2E0A22E160ED862579A50071898D/%24file/SubversionUpdateSite.pdf)) for Domino version 9.0.1, in order to integrate SVN with Domino Designer. I am getting the following error in an alert box on completion of widget creation :
**"The widget failed to be created. Check log for errors"**

**The logs show up :** 
com.ibm.rcp.toolbox.prov.provider.ProvController provision SEVERE com.ibm.rcp.toolbox.prov.provider.ProvController provision lipse.team.svn.revision.graph_0.7.9.I20100512-1900 is not installed on the platform. CWPPR0030W: Feature org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.capabilities_0.7.9.I20100512-1900 is not installed on the platform. CWPPR0030W: Feature org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector_2.2.2.I20100512-1900 is not installed on the platform. CWPPR0030W: Feature org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit_2.2.2.I20100512-1900 is not installed on the platform. CWPPR0030W: Feature org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit16_2.2.2.I20100512-1900 is not installed on the platform. WARNING com.ibm.rcp.provisioning.internal.impl.ProvisioningServiceImpl process

Any pointers from here would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you are using Subversive, not Subclipse.  Probably want to change your tags.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks @MarkPhippard

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote and accept it then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've missed some prerequisites. Did you install Eclipse SVN Connector et al?

I suggest double-checking this because the error complains about missing SVNKit / SVN Connector and some related stuff. Looks like that the instruction you refer to considers you having these prerequisites already in place.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking time to reply.  The **SVNUpdateSite** project in OpenNTF site has all the necessary features. When I create a Widget in Notes using the URL of this UpdateSite, all the mentioned features in the exception log (such as **org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.capabilities_0.7.9.I20100512-1900, org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit_2.2.2.I20100512-1900, ..**)and few others show up automatically.  I chose all these features as per the documentation link in my post. So these features get installed from the UpdateSite they provide. I don't think it is a pre-requisite.

Comment: I will anyway try installing the SVN connector plugin you had mentioned and re-try the Widget creation step. Thanks again.